# Not able to select specific column in Get-Disk

Tags: powershell

I have the below data in csv file

```
"Server","Disk ###","Status","Size","Free"
"s1","Disk 0","Online","100 GB","1024 KB"
"s1","Disk 1","Online","6144 MB","1024 KB"
"s1","Disk 2","Online","200 GB","1024 KB"
"s1","Disk 3","Online","10 GB","1024 KB"
```

expected:

```
"Server","Disk ###","Status","Size","Free", "Total Size"
"s1","Disk 0","Online","100 GB","1024 KB","100 GB"
"s1","Disk 1","Online","6144 MB","1024 KB","60 GB"
"s1","Disk 2","Online","200 GB","1024 KB","100 GB"
"s1","Disk 3","Online","10 GB","1024 KB","2.44 TB"
```

I want to add **Total Size** column to this from **Get-Disk** command

but I am not able to select the column

I tried using like below

```
Get-Disk | Select-Object Total Size
```

```
Get-Disk | Select-Object 'Total Size'
```

But it is giving blank output.

Please let me know what is the issue

tried like below

```
$dataa= Get-Disk | Select-Object -Property @{n="TotalSize";e={'{0:n2} GB' -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}} | ft

Import-Csv -path c:\infile.csv |
Select-Object *,@{Name='TotalSize';Expression={$dataa}} | 
Select-Object "Server","Disk ###","Status","Size","Free", "TotalSize" |
Export-Csv -path C:\Outfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Getting data like

```
"Server","Disk ###","Status","Size","Free","TotalSize"
"s1","Disk 0","Online","100 GB","1024 KB","Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData"
"s1","Disk 1","Online","6144 MB","1024 KB","Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData"
"s1","Disk 2","Online","200 GB","1024 KB","Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData"
"s1","Disk 3","Online","10 GB","1024 KB","Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData"
```

Comment: The real name of the property is `Size`: `Get-Disk |% Size`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Get-Disk` outputs, it does some formatting to display in a nice layout. However, It doesn't actually have all the properties that are in the default output.

To see the properties that actually exist, run:

```
Get-Disk 0 | Format-List *
```

The only properties related to size that you're likely to see are `AllocatedSize` and `Size`. If you look at [the MS doc for the MSFT_Disk CIM class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/msft-disk) that `Get-Disk` returns, you'll see that `AllocatedSize` is "The amount of space, in bytes, that is currently used on the disk." and `Size` is "Total size of the disk, in bytes."

So, to get something like your output, you'd need something like:

```
Get-Disk |
Select-Object -Property @{n='Server';e={hostname}},
    @{n='Disk ###';e={'Disk {0}' -f $_.Number}},
    @{n='Status';e={$_.OperationalStatus}},
    @{n='Size';e={'{0:n2} GB' -f ($_.AllocatedSize / 1GB)}}, 
    @{n='Free';e={'{0:n2} GB' -f (($_.Size - $_.AllocatedSize)/1GB)}}, 
    @{n='TotalSize';e={'{0:n2} GB' -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}} |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The data for first 4 columns I already have in csv. I need to append the output of `@{n='TotalSize';e={'{0:n2} GB' -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}} |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` to the existing csv as new column. how to do that?